# How to pass arguments from an Access form to SQL Query with "IN" clause?

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I'm having trouble getting this query to display any results.

```
SELECT Evaluation_Table.*
FROM Evaluation_Table
WHERE (Evaluation_Table.Test_ID 
In ([Forms]![Test Data]![Group_Test_IDs]));
```

The control, `[Group_Test_IDs]` is a textbox that contains a string of IDs. For example it just contains numbers separated by commas: 1,2,3,4,5. 
While debugging, If I changed the query to look like this, it properly returns records:

```
SELECT Evaluation_Table.*
FROM Evaluation_Table
WHERE (Evaluation_Table.Test_ID 
In (1,2,3,4,5));
```

I can't seem to find the proper syntax. SQL in Access can sometimes be weird.

Comment: you could try having them enter the IDs into a table instead of a textbox and then doing a join

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can't seem to find the proper syntax.

That's because there is none.

The IN selection cannot be dynamic; your only option is to rewrite the SQL via VBA.

Comment: I just discovered the query will work if the textbox contains a single number. example: 3. So the control can be passed. The purpose of the IN clause is to be able to find records in a list. My syntax for the IN clause itself is correct. For some reason I'm unable to send multiple values separated by commas.

Comment: Well, that's exactly the issue. One value will do, a list will not. Neither will a function. You will have to write out the list and somehow insert or append it to the SQL without the list.

Comment: gotchya.
I ended up working around this by using vb as you originally suggested. Thanks for the insight.